# python prints variables but wont write to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing

So theres some data I'm trying to log and I cant for the life of me figure out why part of it writes to the file but the other doesn't:

For example take:

```
filename = mydoc.txt
toLog = {'bought':{nestedDictionary}, 'sold':{nestedDictionary}}
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    print('trades:\nbought:', file=file) 
    for price, amount in toLog['bought'].items(): 
        print(f"{price} : {amount}", file=file)
        print(f"sanity check : {price} : {amount}")
    print('sold:', file=file)
    for price, amount in toLog['sold'].items(): 
        print(f"{price} : {amount}", file=file)
        print(f"sanity check : {price} : {amount}")
    print('\norderbook:\nbids:', file=file)
    for price, amount in self.orderBook['bids'].items():
        print(f"{price} : {amount}", file=file)
    print('asks:', file=file)
    for price, amount in self.orderBook['asks'].items():  
        print(f"{price} : {amount}", file=file)
    print(json.dumps({'trades': toLog, 'orderbook': self.orderBook}), file=file)
```

The `self.orderBook['bids']` and `self.orderBook['asks']` write to file no problem but toLog doesnt... it iterates fine asnd prints the values to console ... but not to file ...
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Use `file.write()` instead of `print`

Comment: Uhhh, so it saeems as though `file.write` just causes a break out of the function this code is contained in, like nothing after `file.write` gets executed .... strange .... This doesn't make any sense

Comment: My advice is to reduce the complexity of your loops first and then test with `file.write`. E.g., use a list and then iterate through the list and write the items into the file. If that works, add more complexity using more loops and content.